# Rails API app: Unable to make work request Rspecs

Tags: rspec, devise, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

## Controller Code

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Api
  module V1
    class MarketplacesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_api_v1_user!
      ...
      def index
        render json: Marketplace.all, status: :ok,
               include: 'url'
      end
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

## First Approach

I have created this method in a helper file

```rb
# spec/requests_helper.rb file

def login(user)
  post api_v1_user_session_path, params: {
    email: user.email, password: user.password
  }.to_json, as: :json
end
```

and use it in my rspec file:

```rb
# spec/requests/api/v1/marketplace_spec.rb file
require "rails_helper"
require "requests_helper"

RSpec.describe Marketplace, :type => :request do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  context "when signed in" do
    it "returns all marketplaces" do
      login(user)
      get "/api/v1/marketplaces"

      expect(response.body).not_to include('redirected') # temporary while finding out why I get a redirect HTML
    end
  end
end
```

but the login method throws:

```json
"{\"success\":false,\"errors\":[\"Invalid login credentials. Please try again.\"]}"
```

the sign in request's body is:

```json
"\"{\\\"email\\\":\\\"test_user@test.te\\\",\\\"password\\\":\\\"password\\\"}\""
```

So, it seems the password sent in the body is the same password for the created user, as defined in this factory:

```rb
# spec/factories/users.rb file
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, class: 'User' do
    name { 'A user' }
    uid { 'test_user@test.te' }
    email { 'test_user@test.te' }
    password { 'password'}
  end
end
```

and finally, the request to `/api/v1/marketplaces` throws:

```json
"{"errors":[\"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.\"]}"
```

Which is expected, since the sign in was not successful as previously shown.

## Second Approach

Instead of my login method, I use the sign in helper:

```rb
# spec/requests/api/v1/marketplace_spec.rb file
require "rails_helper"
require "requests_helper"

RSpec.describe Marketplace, :type => :request do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  context "when signed in" do
    it "returns all marketplaces" do
      sign_in user
      get "/api/v1/marketplaces"

      expect(response.body).not_to include('redirected') # temporary while finding out why I get a redirect HTML
    end
  end
end
```

which is available by adding in the `spec/rails_helper.rb` file:

```rb
...
config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request # if Rails.env.test?
```

but, for doing this, suddenly the request's response body of `get "/api/v1/marketplaces"` is:

```html
<html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://www.example.com/api/v1/auth/sign_in\">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

which is a little weird to me, since I'm doing a rails API

## Third Approach

The same as the previous one, but this time I tried to change this "example.com" thing by adding to the `config/environments/test.rb` file:

```rb
...
config.action_controller.default_url_options = {
  host: 'localhost:3000', # or whatever your host is
  port: '3000'
}
```

But the response's body of `get "/api/v1/marketplaces"` is

```html
<html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/sign_in\">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you post the controller code for the session and the marketplace?

Comment: @Chiperific I edited the post and included the most important things in it. I am not able to post the whole thing. I don't think it's too relevant, though, since what is not being done is the actual authentication, and that would be regardless of any controller or the code in it.

Comment: Methods 2 and 3 feel like a Devise setting that you need to change to make it API and not HTML, but I think it will still redirect you. Method 1 seems like it should work. I would put a debugger right before the `post` call and see why those credentials aren't matching a database record.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://www.example.com/api/v1/auth/sign_in\">redirected</a>.</body></html>
      => this errors is rise beacuse the user is not sign_in yet.
   Firstly you need to add devise configuration code line in your rails_helper or spec_helper.rb file as: 
        config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
Then start to wirte your spec. 
               

     RSpec.describe Marketplace type: :request do 
        let(:user) {create :user}
         before(:each) do 
           sign_in(:user)
         end
       describe " " do 
         it ' ' do 
          #your request
         end
       end
    end
```